# Can't Drop Column (pyspark / databricks)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have dataframe where I simply want to delete a column. Here is snippet of data:

[image]

I want to drop the "value" column. I have tried the following:

```
df.drop(col("value"))
df.drop("value")
df.drop(df.value)
```

I encounter no errors, but the column remains. Do I have to remove the data from the column first? I would not think so. Is there a way to force it to remove the column? Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dataframes are immutable, you must refer the variable after dropping it:

```py
df = df.drop("value")
```